# Approach for transforming website start animation (Raphael.js) to navigation menu (controllable HTML tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, raphael

Being a novice in client side technologies, especially the one that create animations, I still find difficult to use the appropriate approach concerning the front page of my website.

My goal is to load first an animation that will be transformed to a concrete HTML menu that I can,  thus, handle and manage with a javascript library (like jQuery).

Let's take for example this animation created by Raphael.js:

```
$(function () {
                var canvasWidth= $("#canvas").width();
                var canvasHeight= $("#canvas").height();

                var archtype = Raphael("canvas",canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, Radius) {
                // Logic for drawing
                };

                my_arc= = archtype.path().attr({
                    "stroke-width": 3,
                    arc: [r, h, 0, 100, r],
                });

                my_arc=.animate({
                    arc: [2*r, 2*h, 100, 100, 2*r]
                            }, 1200, "ease-in-out",function(){       

                                $("#menu").append('<li>Item 1</li>');
                               } //end callback
    );
```

Under:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

**Questions:**
Should I superimpose the `div#menu` on `div#canvas` using CSS so that menu item `<li>` fit exactly with the animation target position? 
Or should I find a way to link between Rapahel.js and javascript so that the canvas elements (`<svg>`,  `<path>` ...) are transformed or nested with future `<li>`??

Your help is so much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the `#menu` like a popover/tooltip? Are you asking if superimposing is a good strategy vs writing a custom tooltip in svg?

Comment: Thank you @Parris for ur time. I mean by `#menu` a `div` where I will put by jQuery some nested `<li>`s. I think you gave me a good hint by talking about custom svg. Do you mean a drawed menu that will act as HTML menu (no need to superimpose additional html with jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting yourself up for a world of hurt with this approach.

Even if you succeed in tracking the movements of all of the elements in your animation and then replacing them with identical-looking HTML elements where they end up, you will be forcing yourself into using absolute positioning for every element involved, which in my mind defeats the purpose of turning them into HTML elements.

If you're okay with having a fixed layout for your page (by which I mean having a layout that cannot respond to differing screen sizes and shapes except by scaling the entire layout up or down), then you might as well just attach event handlers to the svg elements to handle the interactions. Raphael had lots of built-in methods for handling element events, such as [`Element.click()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click) and [`Element.hover()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover). That way you can just stick with the end state of your svg animation as the default layout for your site, and add the behaviors right to the svg itself without swapping out DOM and having to deal with what will likely be a ton of sticky edge-cases.

If you're not happy with a fixed layout, then you're going to have an awful time trying to adjust your animation so that it ends up with elements in the proper places to make the page have the layout that is needed for differing device/screen sizes. In this case you might be better off scrapping the svg idea altogether and see if you can get something close to the animations you want by starting with HTML elements, and manipulating them with jQuery.

<del>--EDIT--

I just reread your question, and realized that you were using Raphael to manipulate a `canvas` rather than `svg`. My suggestion would be that you consider using Raphael to render svg, for the same reasons I stated above.

SVG is really neat because it can be drawn and animated easily, but instead of being rasterized to a canvas, it is made up of a hierarchy of tagged elements, much like HTML. In fact, you can even style them with your CSS.</del>

Comment: +1 before finishing reading, because really I started being forced to use absolute postion.

Comment: I don't feel i understood well your edit. In fact I dont use canvas, I  use a empty div with id canvas. Inside this div my svg paths are drawn. I hope i was clear.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes much more sense.